# Store values inserted in form inside an array

Tags: angular, typescript, api

Application in angular to read barcodes.

**read.component.html**

```
<form #f="ngForm" class="mt-3 text-center" id="myform" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)">
          <div class="text-center">
            <input type="text" maxlength="13" name="barcode" class="form-control text-center mt-2" [(ngModel)]="barcode" placeholder="Barcode"> 
          </div>
        </form>
```

**read.component.ts**

```
export class ReadComponent implements OnInit {

  barcode:string;
  codEspec:Number;
  DiaHoraEspecs:string;

  reads: Ticket[];

  constructor(private ticketlineservice: TicketlineService, 
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private snackBar: MatSnackBar) {
      this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
        this.codEspec = params['CodEspec'];
        this.DiaHoraEspecs = params['DiaHoraEspecs'];
    });
     }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  onSubmit(f: NgForm){    

    var element = document.getElementById("ticket");
    var barcodes = []; //array to store barcodes
    barcodes.push(this.barcode);  //insert barcode inside array

    for(var i = 0; i < barcodes.length; i++){

        if(barcodes[i] == this.barcode){  //compare barcode read with the ones inside the array

          this.snackBar.open("Ticket already read!",'', {
            duration: 2000,
            verticalPosition: 'top',
            horizontalPosition: 'end',
            panelClass: ['snack-error'],
            });       
            element.setAttribute("style", "visibility: hidden;");
            f.resetForm();

         }else{

    this.ticketlineservice.CheckTicket(this.barcode, this.codEspec, this.DiaHoraEspecs).subscribe(reads => {

      if(Array.isArray(reads)){
        this.reads = reads;
    }
    else if(typeof reads === 'string' ){
        this.reads = [];
    }
    else{
         this.reads = [reads];
    }

    // console.log('reads = ' + reads);
      if(reads != null){
        this.snackBar.open("Ticket valid!",'', {
          duration: 2000,
          verticalPosition: 'top',
          horizontalPosition: 'end',
          panelClass: ['snack-sucess'],
          });
          element.setAttribute("style", "visibility: visible;");
        }else{
          this.snackBar.open("Ticket not found!",'', {
            duration: 2000,
            verticalPosition: 'top',
            horizontalPosition: 'end',
            panelClass: ['snack-error'],
            });       
            element.setAttribute("style", "visibility: hidden;");
        }
        f.resetForm();
    });
  }
}
  }

refresh(): void {
  window.location.reload();
}


}
```

**Problem:** So I have an angular application that consumes an API, this api checks if the barcode is valid or not valid. Since it has not kind of status, saying if it was already read or not, I'm trying to achieve that in frontend.
So I created an array to store every barcode read and compare the values inside that array with the ones read. But every time I read a new barcode it enters my first `if` condition even if the barcode isn't inside the array. Also if could give me an ideia to store the values and not lose them when the user reloads the page I would appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get you right, think about using the Angular `FormArray`:
https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray